# Are there any publicly available SAML Identity Providers?

Tags: .net, vb.net, saml, saml-2.0

I am writing a test application that needs to parse SAML received from a WebRequest. Are there any services out there that allow you to get a SAML response?

I am looking to do something that may work like:

```
 Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("URL")


    Dim Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

    'Parse SAML From Response
```

Does something like this exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Answer (score 0):

Feide OpenIDP used to have one but I see it's now shut down.

Have a look at [SSO Circle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/samlopenid-idp/).

Also [Kentor](http://stubidp.kentor.se/).

Or run up your own instance of Shibboleth.